# Why duplicate rows after Where with group by subquery?

Tags: oracle

My goal is to get a list of a product IDs last updated status and I have two tables below. The issues is I'm getting additional rows when I'm expecting to only receive the latest date.

If I test the single query to get the most recent ID/date, I'm getting the right amount of rows. When I try to combine my product table to it to add more descriptive information, I'm getting some IDs with two rows returned. Usually the last two statuses but its not for every single ID.

If I look at the dates, it seems I'm getting the last two status updates instead of just the most recent date like I was expecting.

```
select ID, max(Last_Updated) from Transactions group by ID <-- works fine 

select p.ID, p.Product, T.Last_Updated from Products P  <-- things start to get weird
inner join Transactions T on p.ID = T.ID
where p.ID in (1,2,3)
and T.Last_Updated in (select ID, max(Last_Updated) from Transactions group by ID)
order by p.ID desc
```

**Products Table**

| ID | Product |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Blueberry Muffin |
| 2 | Chocolate Chip Cookie |
| 3 | Apple |

**Transactions Table**

| ID | Status | Last_Updated |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | purchased | 1/2/2023 11:16:05 am |
| 1 | added-inventory | 1/2/2023 11:00:01 am |
| 1 | displayed | 1/2/2023 11:05:22 am |
| 1 | deleted-inventory | 1/2/2023 11:17:12 am |
| 2 | etc | etc |
| 3 | etc | etc |

**Actual results**

| ID | Product | Status | Last_Updated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Blueberry Muffin | purchased | 1/2/2023 11:16:05 am |
| 1 | Blueberry Muffin | deleted-inventory | 1/2/2023 11:17:12 am |
| 3 | Chocolate Chip Cookie | deleted-inventory | 1/2/2023 11:25:11 am |
| 2 | Apple | deleted-inventory | 1/2/2023 11:22:35 am |

**Expected results**

| ID | Product | Status | Last_Updated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Blueberry Muffin | deleted-inventory | 1/2/2023 11:17:12 am |
| 3 | Chocolate Chip Cookie | deleted-inventory | 1/2/2023 11:25:11 am |
| 2 | Apple | deleted-inventory | 1/2/2023 11:22:35 am |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add attribute columns in an aggregate query, you have to either include them in the GROUP BY which changes your aggregates' granularity, or apply an aggregate to them (like MAX) which can give you undesired results by mixing values from different rows.

Your last query has two issues:

```
and T.Last_Updated in (select ID, max(Last_Updated) from Transactions group by ID)
```

You have one column in the parent (last_updated) and are applying that to two columns in the subquery. Corrected it would be:

```
and (p.pid,T.Last_Updated) in (select ID, max(Last_Updated) from Transactions group by ID)
```

But if last_updated has 1 second granularity and there are multiple records for the same date you can still get more rows than you want using this method. It also requires duplicating potentially a lot of logic between the parent block and the subquery.

Here are some other options:

If you need only the last_updated from transactions:

```
    SELECT p.*,
           (SELECT MAX(t.last_updated)
              FROM Transactions T
             WHERE p.ID = T.ID) last_updated
      FROM Products P
     WHERE p.ID in (1,2,3)
```

If you need other columns from transactions:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT p.*,
               t.othercol1,
               t.othercol2,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p.id ORDER BY t.last_updated DESC) seq
          FROM Products P
               inner join Transactions T on p.ID = T.ID
         WHERE p.ID in (1,2,3))
 WHERE seq = 1
```

Comment: Thanks Paul, you also pointed out another issue I was noticing where the transactions table DOES have duplicate rows with the same datetime stamp which was also skewing the results.